# Dictionaries, for loop, and python

Tags: python, loops

```
fhand = open('mail.txt')
days = dict()

for line in fhand:
    split = line.split()
    if line.startswith('From') and len(split) > 2:
        days[str(split[2])] = days.get(str([split[2]]), 0) + 1
    else: 
        continue
print days
```

And this is the output:

```
{'Fri': 1, 'Thu': 1, 'Sat': 1}
```

I'm trying to record the number of times a word is used through a dictionary. But the dictionary doesn't update its values and only gives me the last line's dictionary.

Any help would be appreciated. If need be I can provide the text file.

If I change the location of the `print days` to be inside the for loop then this is what I get (shrunk down because it's too large):

```
{'Sat': 1}
{'Sat': 1}
{'Sat': 1}
{'Sat': 1}
{'Sat': 1}
{'Sat': 1}
{'Sat': 1}
{'Sat': 1}
{'Sat': 1}
{'Sat': 1}
{'Sat': 1}
{'Sat': 1}
{'Sat': 1}
{'Sat': 1}
{'Sat': 1}
{'Sat': 1}
{'Sat': 1}
{'Sat': 1}
{'Sat': 1}
{'Sat': 1}
{'Sat': 1}
{'Sat': 1}
{'Sat': 1}
{'Sat': 1}
{'Sat': 1}
{'Sat': 1}
{'Sat': 1}
{'Sat': 1}
{'Sat': 1}
{'Sat': 1}
{'Sat': 1}
{'Sat': 1}
{'Sat': 1}
{'Sat': 1}
{'Sat': 1}
{'Sat': 1}
{'Sat': 1}
{'Sat': 1}
{'Sat': 1}
{'Sat': 1}
{'Sat': 1}
{'Sat': 1}
{'Sat': 1}
{'Sat': 1}
{'Sat': 1}
{'Sat': 1}
{'Sat': 1}
{'Sat': 1}
{'Sat': 1}
{'Sat': 1}
{'Sat': 1}
{'Sat': 1}
{'Sat': 1}
{'Sat': 1}
{'Sat': 1}
{'Sat': 1}
{'Sat': 1}
{'Sat': 1}
{'Sat': 1}
{'Sat': 1}
{'Sat': 1}
{'Sat': 1}
{'Sat': 1}
{'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Thu': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Thu': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Thu': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Thu': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Thu': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Thu': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Thu': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Thu': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Thu': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Thu': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Thu': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Thu': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Thu': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Thu': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Thu': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Thu': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Thu': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Thu': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Thu': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Thu': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Thu': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Thu': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Thu': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Thu': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Thu': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Thu': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Thu': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Thu': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Thu': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Thu': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Thu': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Thu': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Thu': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Thu': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Thu': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Thu': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Thu': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Thu': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Thu': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Thu': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Thu': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Thu': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Thu': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Thu': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Thu': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Thu': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Thu': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Thu': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Thu': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Thu': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Thu': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Thu': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Thu': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Thu': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Thu': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Thu': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Thu': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Thu': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Thu': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Thu': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Thu': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Thu': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Thu': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Thu': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Thu': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Thu': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Thu': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Thu': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Thu': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Thu': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Thu': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Thu': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Thu': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Thu': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Thu': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Thu': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Thu': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Thu': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Thu': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Thu': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Thu': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Thu': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Thu': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Thu': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Thu': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Thu': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Thu': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Thu': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Thu': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Thu': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Thu': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Thu': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Thu': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Thu': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Thu': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Thu': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Thu': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Thu': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Thu': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Thu': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Thu': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Thu': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Thu': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Thu': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Thu': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Thu': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Thu': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Thu': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Thu': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Thu': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Thu': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Thu': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Thu': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Thu': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Thu': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Thu': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Thu': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Thu': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Thu': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Thu': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Thu': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Thu': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Thu': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Thu': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Thu': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Thu': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Thu': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Thu': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Thu': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Thu': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Thu': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Thu': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Thu': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Thu': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Thu': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Thu': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Thu': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Thu': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Thu': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Thu': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Thu': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Thu': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Thu': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Thu': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Thu': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Thu': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Thu': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Thu': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Thu': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Thu': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Thu': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Thu': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Thu': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Thu': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Thu': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Thu': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Thu': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Thu': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Thu': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Thu': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Thu': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Thu': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Thu': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Thu': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Thu': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Thu': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Thu': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Thu': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Thu': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Thu': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Thu': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Thu': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Thu': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Thu': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Thu': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Thu': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Thu': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Thu': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Thu': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Thu': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Thu': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Thu': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Thu': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Thu': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Thu': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Thu': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Thu': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Thu': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Thu': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Thu': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Thu': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Thu': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Thu': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Thu': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Thu': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Thu': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Thu': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Thu': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Thu': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Thu': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Thu': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Thu': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Thu': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Thu': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Thu': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Thu': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Thu': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Thu': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Thu': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Thu': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Thu': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Thu': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Thu': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Thu': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Thu': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Thu': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Thu': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Thu': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Thu': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Thu': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Thu': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Thu': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Thu': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Thu': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Thu': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Thu': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Thu': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Thu': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Thu': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Thu': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Thu': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Thu': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Thu': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Thu': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Thu': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Thu': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Thu': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Thu': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Thu': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Thu': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Thu': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Thu': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Thu': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Thu': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Thu': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Thu': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Thu': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Thu': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Thu': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Thu': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Thu': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Thu': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Thu': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Thu': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Thu': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Thu': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Thu': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Thu': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Thu': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Thu': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Thu': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Thu': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Thu': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Thu': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Thu': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Thu': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Thu': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Thu': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Thu': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Thu': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Thu': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Thu': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Thu': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Thu': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Thu': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Thu': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Thu': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Thu': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Thu': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Thu': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Thu': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Thu': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Thu': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Thu': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Thu': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Thu': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Thu': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Thu': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Thu': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Thu': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Thu': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Thu': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Thu': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Thu': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Thu': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Thu': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Thu': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Thu': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Thu': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Thu': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Thu': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Thu': 1, 'Sat': 1}
{'Fri': 1, 'Thu': 1, 'Sat': 1}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "the last line's dictionary?". Also, there is no need for an `else` clause with a `continue`

Comment: I will edit my question to include the output. Also, thanks, I've just started learning python.

Comment: glad you got your problem solved.  That looks like a syntax error.  In the future always copy and paste the complete traceback with your question.  That will help others help you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is there a typo here? `days.get(str([split[2]]), 0)`
shouldn't it be `days.get(str(split[2]), 0)?`